# can we generate automatic documentation from api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I am using Lambda API gateway REST API with serverless. I want to generate automatic API docs instead of writing manually in open API. I saw this documentation from Amazon
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-export-api.html

When I use this it is not generating Response properly. It generates something like this

```
responses:
    200:
      description: "200 response"
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: "#/components/schemas/Empty"
```

I want to know if there is anything I am doing wrong or if there is any other way to generate docs for serverless API gateway.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have your response modeled. For example, here's how you'd do it with the SAM framework:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-api.html#sam-api-gatewayresponses

The export generates an openapi or swagger definition from your api. Then. you can use openapi-generator-cli to generate docs (and also client libraries and other goodies)

for example:

```
aws apigateway get-export --parameters extensions='apigateway' --rest-api-id abcdefg123 --stage-name dev --export-type oas30 openapi.yaml
```

then

```
openapi-generator-cli generate -i openapi.yaml -g html -o doc
```

See more doc examples here:

https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators#documentation-generators